# Powershell 2.0 : issue import-Module in a background job

Tags: powershell

I launch a script in backgroung using Start-Job command.

In this script, I load a module using Import-Module. The job stay blocked in the running state at the Import-Module step.

The same behaviour occurs when :
- dotsourcing a module
- loading the module via -InitializationScript Start-Job command.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score -2):

Exactly you must import as start-job. ..... - initialscript {import-module here're}